# Sending Json along with multipart file in SpringBoot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a collection of optional parameters to a SpringBoot controller, along with a multipart file, but can't figure out how.

Without the multipart file, this works fine

```
public ResponseEntity<ViewModel> performOperationOnFilePath(@Valid @RequestBody final FileOperationFileContract requestBody)
```

where FileOperationFileContract is a POJO that looks like this

```
public class FileOperationFileContract {
    @NotBlank(message = "The filepath is required")
    private String filePath;

    private Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setOptions(final String name, final String value) {
        options.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

Here's what I tried with the multipart file

```
public ResponseEntity<ViewModel> performOperationOnFile(@RequestParam(name="myfile") final MultipartFile file, @RequestPart(name="options", required=false) final FileOperationMultipartFileContract requestBody)
```

where FileOperationMultipartFileContract is a POJO that looks like this

```
public class FileOperationMultipartFileContract {
    private Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setOptions(final String name, final String value) {
        options.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

This seems to work if I specify the Json payload in Postman like this (note that I must specify the content-type as application/json, or I get the message "'application/octet-stream' not supported"

[image]

But if there is no json part sent, I get a 403.  I want the option collection to just be empty or null.  In other words, I want it to default to {}

I've tried RequestPart and RequestParam, but there's no difference.  I've also tried it with and without the @Valid annotation

How can I do this?

Update: I think that I figured out that my problem does not have as much to do with Spring as it does with what I'm trying to do with the `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` annotations. If I change FileOperationFileContract to have regular fields, it works.  But my guess is that the way I have it doesn't work very well with null.  Although if the value is null, there should be no calls to `setOptions`.  Any ideas?

Comment: You may try this https://medium.com/@pankajsingla_24995/multipart-request-with-request-body-using-spring-boot-and-test-using-postman-6ea46b71b75d

Comment: I don't think this really helps.  It's suggesting uploading a file with the json, which doesn't really work for me.  I just want to be able to specify a default value for the object, such as @RequestParm(name="options", defaultValue="{}")

Comment: Did you try with  `required = false` option ?, I use it with the @RequestPart annotation  see https://github.com/eljaiek/sb-mvc-multipart

Comment: Yes, see my code above.  I have required=false   
Hmm, your code looks pretty similar to what I want to do.  Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @eHayik Can you show me an example of a request that you use, either curl or a Postman screenshot?  How do you send in the values for FileMetadata?

Comment: @eHayik Using your example, I get the opposite behaivor. .  If I don't specify metadata on the request, then it comes in as null.  If I specify it, I get a 403.  I'm specifying it with a value like this: {"name": "myname", "contentType": "mycontent", "length": 123}

Comment: Since I use `@RequestPart` I cannot specify a default value that's why I have the `if` statement in line 36.  I'm not sure why you got the 403 passing the file and the json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227682/discussion-between-ehayik-and-peter-kronenberg).

Comment: Actually, I think I got it working.  Your example helped. So many combinations of RequestParam, RequestPart, etc.  I think the piece I was missing that helped was adding `consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` to the PostMapping